# Value Object change after one of variable being change

Tags: javascript, date, object

i need explanation about object or date in javascript.
Because i made some variable with value an object(date), but after i change the a new variable, all variables and the object is being change. I don't know why this happen.

**Here is the code**

```
var expDate = new Date(Date.now());
var minExpDate = expDate;
var maxExpDate = expDate;

minExpDate.setDate(minExpDate.getDate() + 30);
maxExpDate.setDate(maxExpDate.getDate() + parseInt(chf.Get('ExtraDays')));

alert(expDate + '\n' + minExpDate + '\n' + maxExpDate);
```

**but it's okay if i make a new object**

```
var expDate = new Date(Date.now());
var minExpDate = new Date(expDate);
var maxExpDate = new Date(expDate);

minExpDate.setDate(minExpDate.getDate() + 30);
maxExpDate.setDate(maxExpDate.getDate() + parseInt(chf.Get('ExtraDays')));

alert(expDate + '\n' + minExpDate + '\n' + maxExpDate);
```

Sorry for my english and the title is too weird. And i hope to get some explanation why this happen.

Thank you,

Comment: @TheReason, thanks lad.

Answer (score 0):

when you use minExpDate = expDate, you are passing a reference,
so now minExpDate holds a pointer to expDate.

if you want them to be separate, you need to create a new object:

```
var expDate = new Date();
var minExpDate = new Date();
var maxExpDate = new Date();
```